Adding an Extra Qubit into a Quantum Circuit
I am a beginner in quantum computing and am learning about parameterised quantum circuits (in the context of quantum neural networks). What effect does adding an extra qubit into a quantum circuit have on the speed of the computation? I have understood that initially the circuit has gates to encode the classical data, and then there are parameterised gates that need to be optimised. Finally, the output is measured, but I do not understand how do you go about choosing the number of qubits. Is it purely dependent on the type of encoding (eg: basis encoding would mean that you need as many qubits as digits of the data in binary)?
